# "Of the two sisters she is the best." Is the statement grammatically correct?

Tags: adjectives, superlatives

> Of the two sisters she is the **best**.

Because there are only two sisters, 'better' should be used but can we, in some instance use 'best' in this sentence? Would it still be grammatically correct?

Is there a rule which specifies when we are allowed to use superlative degree while comparing two people/things?

Comment: Consider: "This is the best book I've ever read." "How many books have you read?" "One." -- Just because it's possible doesn't mean that we should use it.

Comment: Yes, your example is grammatical for a set of two comparison: though, it is generally considered to be (usually) restricted to informal style. -- *CGEL* page 1162, [2] and [3].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Best* is used all the time when talking about two things or people.

"The best 1998 science fiction movie about people fornicating with chickens inside the Astrodome is *Glubaba*, which is way better than *Raise your right arm*.

> [Usage Note](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/best): According to a traditional rule of grammar, better, not best, should be used in comparisons between two things: *Which house of Congress has the better attendance record?* **This rule is often ignored in practice**, but it still has many devoted adherents. In certain fixed expressions, however, best is used idiomatically for comparisons between two: *Put your best foot forward. May the best team win!*